# How to determine by hand if the given expressions can be interpreted as a flow for the given system?

Tags: dynamical-systems

How can I determine by hand if the following expressions can be the flow of a 1D-system
$\dot{x}=f(x)$.

Expressions:

$\phi_t(x)=x+t$

$\phi_t(x)=t*x$

$\phi_t(x)=e^tx$

$\phi_t(x)=e^xt$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: The maps $\phi_t$ need to be a representation of the *additive* group $(\Bbb R,+)$.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check that

1. $\phi_0(x)=id(x)$
2. $(\phi_t \circ \phi_s) (x)=\phi_{t+x}(x)$

For example, the second and fourth cases do not satisfy requirement 1. On the contrary, the first and third cases satisfy both.